# Why are observable dictionaries implemented by implementing interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop, collections, dictionary, observablecollection

Okay, so I've been looking for a dictionary which throws an event when a piece of data is changed. One of the links I kept coming across is : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx

After inspecting IDictionary interface and Dictionary Class I can clearly see the CRUD (create read update delete). All dictionaries in theory should build on this functionality.

As far as I see it implementing an observable dictionary should be as simple as

```
public class test<K,V> : Dictionary<K,V>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string pCount = "Count";
    private const string pKeys = "Keys";
    private const string pValues = "Values";

    public V this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            object old = base[key];
            base[key] = value;
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value), new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, (V)old)));
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pValues));
        }
    }

    public override void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        if(CollectionChanged!=null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<K,V>(key, value)));
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pCount));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pKeys));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pValues));
        }
    }

    public override void Remove(K key)
    {
        object removed = base[key];
        base.Remove(key);
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removed));
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pCount));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pKeys));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pValues));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : Added more to make it more like the sample and to help clarify the question

I don't understand why all these elaborate dictionaries are being made, Is there something I'm missing? Can someone please explain this to me?

It feels like they're all reinventing the wheel which as far as I see goes against the reusable code which is the point of OO. I really feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: Your example does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reasons why you can't do what you're trying to do:

The indexer, Add, and Remove methods are not virtual.  You cannot `override` the `Add` or `Remove` methods because they aren't virtual.

Because you aren't overriding these methods, you can at best shadow them, anytime the object is typed as an `IDictionary` or `Dictionary` the events won't be triggered.

By using composition instead of inheritance, as is shown in the example you linked to, there is no way for someone given an object of the dictionary to add items without triggering the event, since direct access to the dictionary isn't possible.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for this. This doesn't apply for the particular reason that I wanted to use this; however, now I understand  why it is always implemented from the interface and never the inherited.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` is that they're used by .Net's own [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) (such as WPF's and to a lesser extent winforms').

Your own custom `OnValueAdd`, etc. delegates are not known outside your own class, and they cannot be used by .Net's automatic change notification mechanism.

Comment: I think that my lack of knowledge for the purpose of that particular implementation took away from the question a little bit. What I'm getting at is that the author could have simply inherited from Dictionary and then augmented the class to add those new things. I just don't understand why everyone who does this re-creates the entire dictionary object, especially when most of the classes recreated just wrap the original class.

Comment: @Aelphaeis there's more in that example than just notifying when an item is removed / added to the Dictionary.

Comment: I've edited the question to add what I've seen that he has that I don't and to make it more clear what I mean when I say it feels like they are re-inventing the wheel.

Now it looks a lot more like the example except for most of the methods the default implementation for the dictionary is used.